# Best website to store programming scripts online

Tags: web, save, document, scripting, store

I want a website where-in it will store all my (quick)scripts online. Sometimes I will writing a couple of python scripts to get this done like, getting the list of recent files added, getting the list of added files on a day, or something even more simpler. So I want to document those scripts on a daily basis. How do it online?

Update: Just saw codepad.org. Is there anyother better one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use any version control system for it.

1. A private local svn repository (not really a website)
2. [Github](http://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For Python you can use [Python recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) by ActiveState

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hotscripts.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using snipplr.com to store my code snippets. Mostly because it has a really nice integration with Textmate and an api which makes it possible to integrate it in other tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want simple copy/pasting support and easy adding of new snippets, why not use a wiki? I use wikidot.com for all my stuff, including code snippets, how-tos and interesting links.

Regards,

Sebastiaan

Answer (score 0):

After trying to run all the above suggested ones, codepad.org seemed to be the best solution. Apart from storing scripts, it provides a convenient way to run them online too.

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://live.codenode.org, which supports Python and Sage very well right now, and is planned to support other languages like Ruby, R, etc in the future.